# How to get unwind segue to work between along side a regular segue in the same view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue, unwind-segue

Sorry if the title is a little vague. I'm still learning swift and segues and I have 3 view controllers called `EarthViewController`, `MoonViewController`, and `JupiterViewController`.

These are the segues that work:

```
EarthViewController -> MoonViewController
MoonViewController -> JupiterViewController
JupiterViewController -> MoonViewController, 
and even JupiterViewController -> EarthViewController,
```

but the unwind segue from `MoonViewController -> EarthViewController` keeps throwing a `Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT` error where I have commented `//ERROR HERE` when trying to go back to the Earth view. Here is the layout and code so far:

[image]

EarthViewController (ViewController)

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let des = segue.destination as! MoonViewController 

        if (segue.identifier == "toMoonView")
        {
            print("Went to the moon")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func backFromMoon(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){

        if let scVC = segue.source as? MoonViewController
        {
            print ("Back from the Moon to Earth")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func backFromJupiterToEarth(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){

        if let scVC = segue.source as? JupiterViewController
        {
            print ("Back from Jupiter to Earth")
        }
    }
}
```

MoonViewController

```swift
import UIKit

class MoonViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

//------------------------------------------------------------------------
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let des = segue.destination as! JupiterViewController //<- ERROR HERE

        if (segue.identifier == "toJupiterView")
        {
            print("Went to Jupiter")
        }
    }
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    @IBAction func backFromJupiter(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){

        if let scVC = segue.source as? JupiterViewController
        {
            print ("Back from Jupiter to the Moon")
        }
    }
}
```

JupiterViewController (Nothing added yet)

```swift
import UIKit

class JupiterViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Don’t force downcast - in this case the destination view controller isn’t what you think it is and so the five downcast fails. The exception message will tell you what the destination object actually is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function in `MoonViewController`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let des = segue.destination as! JupiterViewController //<- ERROR HERE

    if (segue.identifier == "toJupiterView")
    {
        print("Went to Jupiter")
    }
}
```

is called both for regular segues and unwind segues.  When you are segueing to `JupiterViewController` then `segue.destination` is indeed of type `JupiterViewController`.  But when you are unwinding to `ViewController`, `segue.destination` is of type `ViewController`.

In this second case, the force cast `as! JupiterViewController` crashes because the type is wrong.

One way to fix that is to move the declaration of `des` inside of the `if` when you have identified the destination:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toJupiterView"
    {
        let des = segue.destination as! JupiterViewController
        print("Went to Jupiter")
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked man thank you!! I would have never guessed that. I'd upvote but it seems I'm one vote away from being able to do so. Thank you again.